# My JavaScript doesn't run when the html is in a form

Tags: javascript, html, django, web

HTML

I have some simple html input here and I would like to put it in a POST form

```
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" id="myTextInputID" placeholder="       Your amazon URL">
    </form>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function search(){
    var inputValue = document.getElementById("myTextInputID").value;
}


document.getElementById("myTextInputID").addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var input = document.getElementById("myTextInputID").value;
      document.getElementById(search());
      var error = document.getElementById("error")
      if (input.includes("https://www.amazon.co.uk/")){
        error.style.display = "none";
      }else{
        error.style.display = "block";
        setTimeout(function(){error.style.display = "none";} ,2000)
        
      }
    }
});
function togglePopup(){
  document.getElementById("popupe-1").classList.toggle("active");

}
```

And I have my if function here when I don't have my user input as a post method it works perfectly fine, but when I add the post method the page just reloads each time and doesn't run my javascript function

Comment: What is the meaning of using document.getElementById(search()); inside eventListener.

Comment: forms have a submit method that you can prevent - did you want to prevent it?

Comment: Are you suggesting that i dont need to refer to another function

Comment: And to answer the second question i want it to show an error message if the user input doesn't meet the criteria, and submit the form if it does

Answer (score 0):

It because when user presses Enter, it triggers the form submit action, and it will reload the page.

To prevent form submit action to be triggers, add `onkeydown="return event.key != 'Enter';"` to your form.

```js
function search(){
    var inputValue = document.getElementById("myTextInputID").value;
}


document.getElementById("myTextInputID").addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var input = document.getElementById("myTextInputID").value;
      document.getElementById(search());
      var error = document.getElementById("error")
      if (input.includes("https://www.amazon.co.uk/")){
        error.style.display = "none";
      }else{
        error.style.display = "block";
        setTimeout(function(){error.style.display = "none";} ,2000)
        
      }
    }
});
function togglePopup(){
  document.getElementById("popupe-1").classList.toggle("active");

}
```

```html
<form action="https://www.google.com" method="POST" onkeydown="return event.key != 'Enter';">
  <input type="text" id="myTextInputID" value="https://www.amazon.co.uk/" />
</form>

<div id="popupe-1">Helloworld</div>
<div id="error">I'm a error</div>
```